# If and partial selection

Tags: list-manipulation

There is some lists and this is consisting of `{a,{b,c},d,e}` elements.
For example,

```
list[1]={{7,{1,1},1,2},{10,{6,2},3,5},{10,{7,2},2,1}}
```

I want to create new lists, It' s like these elements are d>1, a is replaced by the value `e*a`(when d=1 there is unchanged in the elements).
In the case of list[1],`newlist[1]={{7,{1,1},1,2},{10*5,{6,2},3,5},{10*1,{7,2},2,1}}`

So,I started writing from `If[list[[t,3]]>1,`~~~~. (`t` is `Length[list]`)

However, I got an error saying that expression `t` cannot be partially specified.
How can I help you?

Comment: Thank you all for all kinds of answers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {10, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}};
```

#### 1.

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[{a_, {b_, c_}, d_, e_}] := {a If[d > 1, e, 1], {b, c}, d, e}

newlist = Map[f1] @ lst
```

> ```
> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}
> ```

#### 2.

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 [a_, {b_, c_}, d_, e_] := {a If[d > 1, e, 1], {b, c}, d, e}

newlist = MapApply[f2] @ lst
```

> ```
> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}
> ```

#### 3.

You can also use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) as follows:

```
newlst = lst /. {a_, {b_, c_}, d_, e_} /; d > 1 :> {a e, {b, c}, d, e }
```

> ```
> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {10, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}};

SequenceCases[lst, {{a_, b_List, d_, e_}} :>  {If[d > 1, a e, a], b, 
   d, e}]
```

or

```
{If[#3 > 1, #1 #4, #1], #2, #3, #4} & @@@ lst
```

---

*Result*

> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}

Answer (score 4):

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[lista, x : {a_, {b_, c_}, d_, e_} :> If[d > 1, {a e, {b, c}, d, e}, x]]

(**{{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}})
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Parts of Matrices:

```
(* 1:1 copy of lst *)
newlist = lst; 

(* 1st column transformation based on the values of the 1st, 3rd and 4th columns*)
newlist[[;; , 1]] = #1 If[#2 > 1, #3, 1] & @@@newlist[[;; , {1, 3, 4}]]
```

> {7, 50, 10}

```
(* Output newlist *)
newlist
```

> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}

Answer (score 3):

```
foo[a : {__, 1, _}] := a
foo[{a_, b__, c_}] := {a c, b, c}

foo /@ lst
```

{{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

Following the method attempted by OP:

```
lst = {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {10, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}

Table[If[e[[3]] > 1, {e[[1]] e[[4]], e[[2]], e[[3]], e[[4]]}, e], {e, lst}]
```

> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}

```
Table[If[e[[3]] > 1, ReplacePart[e, 1 -> e[[1]] e[[4]]], e], {e, lst}]
```

> {{7, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {50, {6, 2}, 3, 5}, {10, {7, 2}, 2, 1}}